# Code auto-generation and auto-tuning tools or language for C program?

Tags: optimization, compiler-construction, code-generation, abstract-syntax-tree, dsl

I want to use some tools (free is better) or languages to help me do the following two tasks:

**Task 1:** 
1. Read the specification file (text file) the user gives as input. To the user, the format of the specification file is designed by me and the user must follow it.
2. Use the specification input to generate an AST (abstract syntax tree).
3. Transform the AST  into another AST by applying some optimization techniques such loop optimization, blocking or any other optimization I want. (Optional step) 
4. Export the transformed AST to a source code file (C program file).
**Task 2:**
1. Read a source code file (C program file) and generate an AST to represent it.
2. Transform the AST  into another AST by applying some optimization techniques such loop optimization, blocking or any other optimization I want. (To some optimization, I can parameterize it such as the loop unroll depth.)
3. Export the transformed AST to another optimized source file (C program file).

Answer (score 3):

What OP wants in general is a [program transformation system (PTS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation).  PTS are generally capable of accepting an arbitrary syntax specification, building a parser producing ASTs from that syntax, applying source-to-source transforms to map the parsed AST to other ASTs, and then regenerating source text from the final AST.

A specific issue for OP is parsing/unparsing C source code.  Almost none of the PTSs available do this for production C code (ANSI, GCC, MSStudio) and it is quite a lot of work to get this right.  Nor do they provide auxiliary analyses which are needed to do interesting transformations, such as symbol tables, control or data flow analysis.

To my knowledge, only our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html), and [Rose Compiler](http://rosecompiler.org/), have specific support like this for C.

Rose, however, isn't designed to accept a DSL; it violates the PTS model by not allowing arbitrary syntax definitions.  Instead, it uses the EDG parser front end (I think this means it also accepts C++14).  But it can't handle OP's first request easily.  Rose also does "source-to-source" transformations, but does so by hand-written procedural code that crawls the AST.  It is focused on scientific computing, so they have done specific work on blocking loops, etc.

DMS is designed to accept arbitrary grammars (and handles C as well as C++14), and in fact can handle more than one at the same time, so it will support OP's first task directly. DMS does *surface-syntax* (written using C syntax directly) source-to-source rewrites as well as procedural ones.   It has not been used for loop blocking, but DMS has been used to build vector extensions of C++ with code generation for SIMD instructions including appropriate loop optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

The POET (Parameterized Optimization for Empirical Tuning, http://www.cs.uccs.edu/~qyi/poet) script language is one candidate. Are there any other tools or language?

Comment: You might give us some information about what Poet does; the link page contains nothing descriptive.

Comment: Most transformation systems that I've encountered fail at "LifeAfterParsing" (check my bio).  POET is pretty impressive on this front: http://www.cs.uccs.edu/~qyi/poet/documents/tutorial-compiler.pdf  A weakness is the recursive descent parsing; this may work for preprocessed C (maybe not for rather famous ambiguity) but is unlikely to handle the complexity of something like C++.